# How to query data in Cassandra or Riak where the value is a collection?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, data-modeling, riak

How can I query the data in cassandra OR riak if the value of a key in the object is a List

> example=> 
>   Genre[Key] : Pop, rock [Values]

I want to list all songs with the genre rock and so on.

Can I do this using Cassandra/Riak's secondary indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Riak's [secondary indexes](http://wiki.basho.com/Secondary-Indexes.html) can handle this for you.

You would simply store your objects in Riak and index them with the appropriate genre(s).

Pretend your data looks like this (JSON):

```
{ "song":"My awesome song", "genres":["rock", "alternative"] }
```

You would store the object and use binary indexes for the genres (example using curl):

```
curl -v -X PUT \
-d '{ "song":"My awesome song", "genres":["rock", "alternative"] }' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "x-riak-index-genre_bin: rock" \
-H "x-riak-index-genre_bin: alternative" \
http://127.0.0.1:8098/riak/mybucket/mykey1
```

To get all songs indexed with "rock" you'd then do:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8098/buckets/mybucket/index/genre_bin/rock
```

Answer (score 0):

[Riak Search](http://wiki.basho.com/Riak-Search.html) can easily handle that, but you'll probably need to make sure that your entries are properly indexed, for example by concatenating lists to a binary strings.